# How to return "text/html" content for AJAX call using a template engine in sinatra?

Tags: jquery, ajax, sinatra, slim

SO, I have a problem with Ajax (using JQuery) and Sinatra.

I have a route:

```
get '/ajx' do
  content_type 'text/html', :charset => 'utf-8'
  slim :mypartitial, :layout => false
end
```

which is to be called via Ajax "GET":

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#vars').click(function(event){
      $.ajax({  
        type: "GET",  
        url: "/ajx",  
        data: "",
        success: function(data) {  
          $("#result").html(data)
        }  
      }); 
    });
  });
```

But I get no html output and nothing is rendered. I suppose the problem is here

```
 slim :mypartitial, :layout => false
```

but I have no idea how to return a valid html still using the template engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. It needed

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#vars').click(function(event){
    $.ajax({  
      type: "GET",  
      url: "/ajx",  
      data: "",
      success: function(data) {  
        $("#result").html(data)
      }  
    });
  return false;   //  <-- 
  });
});
```